# System.IndexOutOfRangeException in a random generator

Tags: c#, arrays, string, indexing, indexoutofrangeexception

I am trying to make a random sentence generator, and just typed in a bunch of random Warhammer names to test it out. However, I keep getting a `System.IndexOutOfRangeException` error, and I don't know how to fix it. I am very, very new to coding in C#, and don't know too much. The code for just the generator is below:

```
string[] noun = {"Horace Lupercal", "Rogal Dorn", "God Emperor", "Primarch", "Comissar", "Ork Boyz", "T'au Emperor", "Nurgle", "Slaanesh", "Space Marines", "Angron", "Tzeentch", "Lord Inquisitor"};
string[] noun2 = {"Horace Lupercal", "Rogal Dorn", "God Emperor", "Primarch", "Comissar", "Ork Boyz", "T'au Emperor", "Nurgle", "Slaanesh", "Space Marines", "Angron", "Tzeentch", "Lord Inquisitor"};
string[] adj = {"violently", "desperately", "deliberately", "heretically", "murderously", "bloodily", "brutally"};
string[] verb = {"ripped apart", "ate", "consumed", "dismembered", "murdered", "commit a heresy with", "impaled", "shot", "decapitated"};
string[] prep = {"behind", "next to", "in front of", "on", "near", "in", "above", "beneath"};
string[] location = {"Terra", "the galaxy", "Gorstanigrad", "the Imperial Palace", "Krieg", "Cadia"};
Random rand = new Random();
int index = rand.Next(noun.Length);

Console.WriteLine($"{noun[index]} {adj[index]} {verb[index]} {noun2[index]} {prep[index]} {location[index]}");
```

Comment: It doesn't look like all your arrays are the same length. Yet you only have one `index`. Create a random number for each of your arrays, just like you did for `noun`.

Answer (score 1):

The arrays have different lengths. By picking a random index based on the length of the `noun` array, you may get an index that's invalid in some of the shorter arrays. You could however pick a random index for each array separately:

```
int nounIndex = rand.Next(noun.Length);
int adjIndex = rand.Next(adj.Length);
int verbIndex = rand.Next(verb.Length);
int noun2Index = rand.Next(noun2.Length);
int prepIndex = rand.Next(prep.Length);
int locationIndex = rand.Next(location.Length);


Console.WriteLine($"{noun[nounIndex]} {adj[adjIndex]} {verb[verbIndex]} {noun2[noun2Index]} {prep[prepIndex]} {location[locationIndex]}");
```

Also, as a side note, your `noun` and `noun2` arrays have the same content. If this is intentional (and not just a simplification of the code for the post), you can save some memory by having just one `noun` array and two random indexes in it.

Comment: Thank you so much! Just making new indexes for each array worked (obviously). Thanks again!